# Correct RelativeLayout usage please

Tags: android

I have a layout for a listview item and it's displayed incorrectly (book descr goes over the last update date). Can you please help me to fix?

If I set

```
 android:layout_above="@+id/lastUpdatedDt"
```

to the bookDescr item the whole text disappears...

EDIT: I've updated sample according to comments

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/big_card_details"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="false">

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="?android:attr/starStyle"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Book title"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/icon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="470k"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/icon"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lastUpdatedDt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="Updated 27.04.2014 17.10"
    android:textSize="12sp"

    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/icon" />
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/bookDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="false"
    android:textSize="10sp"
    android:text="here should be long description"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@id/bookSize"
    android:layout_below="@+id/bookTitle"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/icon" />



    <!-- this is the button that will trigger sliding of the expandable view -->

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/expand_details_button"
        android:src="@drawable/slide_button_details"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/lastUpdatedDt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/lastUpdatedDt"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/bookSize"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@id/bookSize" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<!-- this is the expandable view that is initially hidden and will slide out when the more button is pressed -->
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/details_expandable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:baselineAligned="false"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
    <!-- put whatever you want in the expandable view -->
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_read"
        android:text="@string/ReadBook"
        style="@style/SlideButtonTheme" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.3"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_action_open_browser"
        style="@style/SlideButtonTheme"
        android:text="@string/OpenInBrowser" />

</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Issues I see so far: **1** - You have too many layouts. **2** - The xmlns is repeated (WRONG!!). **3** - You use `@+id` instead of `@id` when REFERRING to ids (`@+id` should be used only to CREATE new ids). **4** - `fill_parent` is deprecated since API 8. Since API 8, you should use `match_parent`

Comment: 1. I have only 3 layouts (minimum required for the custom view https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView. 2. Thx 3. Didnt know it, thx 4. My min sdk is 8, so I will change it to match_parent, thx

Comment: 1 - You have 4 layouts, you could semplify much (possibly reducing to 1 or two or, in the worst case, 3) - I'm not going to study the question in deep. Keep in mind that the less layouts (and the less controls) you use, the better performances you'll get, and therefore a better user experience.

Comment: Oops sry) didnt noticed LinearLayout in expandable section. Thanks one more time :)

Comment: Try to do your best to flatten the hierarchy. Take full advantage of the relative positioning offered by the RelativeLayout. Try using `compound drawables` instead of ImageViews close to TextViews.

Comment: I'm a newbie to android, but in future I'll try to do it. Now based to slideExpandable sample, it's impossible to have less than 3 layouts. I've edited a question with your suggestions. Issue still exists...

Comment: Moving your code outside SO is not a good practice. You force us to go back and forth. Anyway, I still see `@+id` here and there.

Comment: didn't think about it, I have two monitors) Reverted.

Comment: I still think that the outer LinearLayout is useless. You could move the xmlns into the Relative Layout an use that one as the external container (The inner LinearLayout would be contained into the RelativeLayout and bottom aligned to it - I think you only have to play with the visibility attribute then)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope your aware that the child view in the `RelativeLayout` need to placed `below/above any of the sibling views` or `aligned from the parent`.

The problem here is that , `lastUpdatedDt` is `aligned to parent bottom` , since the parent `RelativeLayout` height is set to `wrap_content`  height will be decided based on the child views , so that `lastUpdatedDt` is placed at the bottom depends on the parent height, which overlap the sibling view.

**FIX :** Just set the `android:layout_below="@+id/bookDescription"` for the `lastUpdatedDt` `TextView` , so that the `lastUpdatedDt` will always be placed bottom of the parent and below `bookDescription` `TextView` sibling.